# position label tree edges using macro

Tags: macros, tikz-trees

In this tree I want the edge labels horizontally aligned, probably nearer the edges. The tree may not be binary.

I would also like to diminish clutter and save typing by putting

```
  \edge node[auto=right] {1};
```

in a macro, but the `\ee` in my mwe fails.

I would prefer a `tikz-qtree` solution but that's not required.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{%
    \edge node[auto=right] {#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
   level distance=1.5cm,sibling distance=1.0cm, 
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
  \Tree [.root
%    \ee{1};
    \edge node[auto=right] {1};
          [.1
            \edge node[auto=right] {1}; 2
            \edge node[auto=right] {2}; 3
          ]
    \edge node[auto=right] {2};          
    [.2
            \edge node[auto=right] {1}; 3 
            \edge node[auto=right] {2}; 4
    ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: **How** does it fail? And aligned with what exactly?

Comment: You can't use `\ee` here because `\edge` isn't defined. The code scans the tokens for `\edge`, for example, and it won't see the `\edge` hidden in `\ee`. You'd need the `\ee` to expand before the scanning got there. Theoretically, you could probably do that with enough `\expandafter`s and so on, but it would do quite the opposite of decluttering the code. All the packages which support the bracket syntax for tree specifications do this, as far as I know. In `forest`, there's a special facility to escape the scanner (used in `prooftrees`). I don't know if `tikz-qtree` has anything similar?

Comment: But you can reduce `inner sep` for the label nodes and specify `anchor` to get them closer to the edges and/or align them with whatever-it-is. That is straightforward. If `tikz-qtree` supports the use of keys in the tree, you could potentially do something there to automate `\edge`? (Really, I'm just saying what I'd do in `forest`.) By the way, you have an excess `]`.

Comment: You can use e.g. `    edge from parent/.append style={every node/.append style={auto=right}},` so you needed repeat the options. But note that `auto=right` precludes aligning the labels on edges from the same parent. (Don't know if that's what you meant by alignment.) You can get around this by flipping left/right, but I'm not sure you can automate that with this package. If you really want to declutter, you should consider `forest`.

Comment: A minimal change might be `\newcommand{\ee}[1]{node[auto=right] {#1}}` and then use it as `\edge\ee{...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from @campa for the macro and searching to find  `node[midway,left]`  solved my problems well enough.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{%
    node[midway,left] {#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
   level distance=1.5cm,sibling distance=0.7cm, 
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
  \Tree [.root
    \edge \ee{1};
    [.1
      \edge \ee{1}; 2
      \edge \ee{2}; 3
    ]
    \edge \ee{2};          
    [.2
      \edge \ee{1};
            [.3
              \edge \ee{1}; 4
              \edge \ee{2}; 5                            
            ]
      \edge \ee{2}; 4
    ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```